# Textbox validation border

Tags: wpf, silverlight, validation, xaml, textbox

I currently have the following red `Border`, signifying invalid entry, around `TextBox`es in an application.

It just doesn't look right to me, it has square borders around rounded corners and the drop shadow is the wrong colour.

What is the best way of achieving a decent looking border around the text boxes?

[Valid XHTML http://www.gumpshen.com/images/window.gif](http://www.gumpshen.com/images/window.gif)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but as a user, I almost prefer that the `Background` color change to a shade of red, with a low opacity value.  It catches the eye well without being too "in your face".

That said, can you get the desired `Border` effect to look better simply by specifying the red border's `CornerRadius` value, while changing the `TextBox`'s `BorderThickness` to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Extract the `TextBox` template using Expression Blend and modify the `ValidationStates` to suit your desires.